# Why does tkinter entry insert in the reverse order?

Tags: python, tkinter

How does inserting text in a tkinter entry work? Like, what is the index? I was doing a codemy.com tkinter challenge for which I create a calculator; I don't understand the number insert part.

Here's my code:

```py
### Calculator
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title = ("Calculator")

display = Entry(root)
display.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 5, padx = 10, pady = 10)

no = ""

def numClicked(NO):
    global no
    no = str(NO) + str(no)
    display.insert(no, NO)
    print (no)

No1 = Button(root, text = 1, padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: numClicked(1))
No1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

No2 = Button(root, text = 2, padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: numClicked(2))
No2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

No3 = Button(root, text = 3, padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: numClicked(3))
No3.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

No4 = Button(root, text = 4, padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: numClicked(4))
No4.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

No5 = Button(root, text = 5, padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: numClicked(5))
No5.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

No6 = Button(root, text = 6, padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: numClicked(6))
No6.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

No7 = Button(root, text = 7, padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: numClicked(7))
No7.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

No8 = Button(root, text = 8, padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: numClicked(8))
No8.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

No9 = Button(root, text = 9, padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: numClicked(9))
No9.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

No0 = Button(root, text = 0, padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: numClicked(0))
No0.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

OperatorM = Button(root, text ="*", padx = 40, pady = 20)
OperatorM.grid(row = 4, column = 0)

OperatorD = Button(root, text ="/", padx = 40, pady = 20)
OperatorD.grid(row = 4, column = 2)

OperatorA = Button(root, text ="+", padx = 40, pady = 20)
OperatorA.grid(row = 5, column = 0)

OperatorS = Button(root, text ="-", padx = 40, pady = 20)
OperatorS.grid(row = 5, column = 2)

OperatorP = Button(root, text ="^", padx = 40, pady = 20)
OperatorP.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

OperatorE = Button(root, text ="  =  ", padx = 40, pady = 20)
OperatorE.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

OperatorC = Button(root, text ="Clear", padx = 40, pady = 20)
OperatorC.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

root.mainloop()
```

Here, I press numbers and they are in the correct order. But when I `print(no)`, it shows in the reverse order (`No` is a number like 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.).

So how does the order get reversed?

Comment: print `str(no) + str(NO)` instead of `str(NO) + str(no)` and you will have in correct order.

Comment: i don't know what you try to do with `insert(no, NO)` but it works as `insert(position, value)` and `Entry` display correctly only because you use value `4321` as `position` - `insert("4321", "4")` - and position `"4321"` is at the end of current value in `Entry` - but you should rather use special tag `"end"` like `insert("end", NO)`

Comment: you should add new number at the end `no = no + str(NO)` or shorter `no += str(NO)`. OR you should keep it as integer or float: `no = 0` at start and later `no = no*10 + NO`

Answer (score 4):

I think that the simplest way to do this is to change your `numClicked` function so that it inserts the `num` at the end of your `display` widget by passing `"end"` as the first argument to the `insert` method:

```py
def numClicked(num):
    display.insert("end", num)
    print(display.get())
```

You don't have to store a global variable for the `display` widget, just use `display.get()` to get the current value of the entry field.